# vscode typescript: 'Add all missing imports' shortcut

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, typescript3.0

I am working on a typescript project (typescript3.x).

I recently noticed the `Add all missing imports` when I click on the bulb which comes when I am using more than one types which are not yet imported as shown below:

[image]

Is there a shortcut for the same?
Or should I request it as a feature?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think vscode now has this feature built in.

The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> gives us options to autofix issues. I found this working even in case of multiple imports and all.

Please let me know if there is any other way to do the same :)

Comment: A great shortcut. I was used to using Ctrl + space, this one gives better suggestions!

Comment: But this shortcut doesn't allow us to import all the missing files in one go. :)

Comment: @MayurAgarwal it shows option to add all missing imports when there is a single module with that name. For Example there are 2 dependencies which are not imported. 1) Logger 2) DateTime(from luxon).
We have mongodb in package.json & as they ship their own logger module, if we try to use a custom logger, then vscode won't show the import all. It will instead show us all the available logger modules. Similarly when we press the shortcut on other item(which is unique), it will show import all & will try to import the first module that ships logger. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 89):

> Is there a shortcut for the same?

Yes, coming in v1.46 (see [v1.46 release notes: add missing imports source action](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#add-all-missing-imports-source-action)):

> #### Add all missing imports source action
>
> VS Code has long supported a quick fix that adds all missing imports
> in a JavaScript or TypeScript file. This iteration, we introduced a
> new `Add all missing imports` source action lets you trigger this from
> anywhere in a file.
>
> This also allows you to set up a keybinding for `Add all missing imports`:
>
> ```
> {
>     "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
>     "command": "editor.action.sourceAction",
>     "args": {
>         "kind": "source.addMissingImports",
>         "apply": "first"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Or even enable `Add all missing imports` on save:
>
> "editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.addMissingImports": "always" },

Comment: Thanks for this. I just created a new issue with a feature request for **Fixing broken imports** because I don't see that addressed by any of these commands. Would love to see this implemented as another time saving feature https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102458. It could probably piggy back quite easily of existing functionality.

Comment: is there a way to add all missing imports in all the files?

Comment: Very cool! Now if only i can somehow trigger it automatically after using some snippets.

Comment: Here are the docs for [`editor.codeActionsOnSave`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-refactoring#_code-actions-on-save), including `"source.addMissingImports"`. Can import the wrong things when there are multiple sources, though. And when you have multiple entries there, [put it first](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164876#issuecomment-1426985465).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean a keyboard shortcut, I don't see the command listed at all in the "File" -> "Preferences" -> "Keyboard Shortcuts" window, so it appears there's no shortcut nor a way to configure one (as of Visual Studio Code 1.28.2).  If the "Add all missing imports" code fix from the TypeScript extension is exposed as a command, then you would be able to assign a shortcut.

Comment: It will be available soon (June 2020) as a global shortcut: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95831